# selenium is not recognizing element in frame

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In selenium web-driver, when I run this code both statements run fine and do not throw any errors i.e. it recognizes 2 frames in the user interface.

The issue is:

1. I see only 1 frame in user interface.
2. When I try to access any element, it says object not visible.

```java
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
```

Solution tried:

Printed screenshot of both the frames to distinguish between the 2, but it prints the same screenshot for both the frames.

Comment: Why are you using a different driver for the switchTo()?  And why is it a problem that if you switch to a non-existent frame, it doesn't throw an error?

Comment: if the frame does not exists in ui, then it should always throw an exception.

Comment: Sure, that's what its supposed to do, and there may be some other IFrame hidden away in the HTML...but I still don't understand why this is a problem...

Comment: right there was a iframe hidden with name 'hid', hence it was showing me 2 frames.
coming back to the original question, it is not recognizing any objects in the outer frame. any idea what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to access elements in the parent page after having switched to an iframe, you will have to return context back to the default content using:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

and then try to access your element.